# Phonegap - Open Local HTML file with File Opener

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I want to print an html file through the phonegap build app.

I'm using android app.

I dont want to use 3rd part service to print, as I dont want client to install additional app.

So I like to open the html in system browser and print it through the default printer provided by the browser like chrome.

Now I'm trying to use window.plugins.fileOpener plugin.
https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/3233

window.plugins.fileOpener.open("file:///sdcard/Android/data/---/www/static/sell/views/print.html");

I have following two questions:
1. Above fileopener command is trying to open the html file in some browser application. Is there a way to say go default to Chrome always?

2. I want to get the html file from the phone, I'm not sure how to get the absolute path. Above path says file not found. How to find the absolute path for a file under our phonegap app.

Answer (score 0):

To get absolute path, may have to try out file plugin. 
And your first question is answered in the fileopener plugin documentation - "Android device will either open the file with proper external application installed on your device or ask you which application to use, if you haven't set before which application to use to open the specific type of file"